# How to connect to CA-Server to search for certificates?

Tags: certificate, remote-access, ca

I have a problem with connecting to the CA-server.  My idea is to revoke certificates through a remote connection. Actually I am admin on my local machine and also on the CA-server. The idea is pretty similar to the following link : [Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2010/05/10/how-to-get-info-from-client-certificates-issued-by-a-ca-c.aspx)

Now my problem is on the following part:

> certView.OpenConnection(strServer + "\" + strCAName);

If I run through this line it show me the error:

> CCertView::OpenConnection The operation was canceled by the user. 0x800704c7 (WIN32: 1223)

Does anybody now this error and can help me?

I can successfully revoke the certificate by a remote connection like this:

> CCertAdmin caAdmin = new CCertAdmin();
>   caAdmin.RevokeCertificate("strServer", "strSerialnumber", reason, DateTime.Now);

So I think there is no problem with the connection to the ca-server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution with the help of the microsoft support.

The problem is that the installationfile of the RSAT 64Bit (Remote Server Administration Tools) is not complete. So there are files missing. The 32Bit version of the RSAT is complete.

Now my problem was that i was programming a webapplikation on a Windows 7 64Bit with RSAT 64Bit installed. But my webapplication was running in 32Bit. So then the error occurs cause there are missing some important files.

The solution is to extract the 32Bit version of RSAT like this: [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928636/en-us)

or

if it is possible you develope your webapplikation on a Windows 7 32Bit with RSAT in 32Bit. Then you won't have any trouble.